# Cannot Update/Insert more rows to the table manually [SQL - mdf file]

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, mdf

I am trying to input some more records to the tables in my database.
When I first created the table, I could easily insert the records into it; but now, after I closed and re-opened Visual Studio, it won't let me to insert more rows into that same table.

I placed my mdf file in the deployment folder. Also, I did google for help but still cannot figure it out, I have to change the properties (copy output directory) of the mdf file to be "Copy if newer or Do not copy", but still doesn't work.

[image]

When I enter the records and click Execute SQL, the new record (TEST0003) just disappears.

Comment: Don't you need to tab off the new item row first? If you hit Execute SQL it will throw your new record away.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I've tried to enter the entire rows before hitting Execute SQL, but still disappear

Comment: No, he means if you hit execute query before you exit the row. 1.) Fill out the entire row. 2.)After its filled in, hit the row above it. This will immediately write the changes to the new row to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to hit Execute SQL Query to manually edit a new row in. The tool will automatically try to write the line you edited. Click out of the row to write the changes. You will see the Pencil picture disappear when written. It will notify you upon failure.